# Position of a QGraphicsItem in scene always NULL

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

For testing purposes, I am trying to draw several rectangles on a scene and add some text inside. The rectangles are supposed to be displayed in one column. They are, but the problem is that the text isn't. All the text is stacked on the top left of the scene.

Futhermore, `pos()` and `scenePos()` always return (0,0) for every box and text.

Here is the code responsible for that:

```
QHash<QString,Picto> Palette::getPics(){
    SpriteSheetManager ssm("sprite_zone"); 
    QList<QString> picNames = ssm.finder->allPic(); //Get all string to be displayed
    QHash<QString,Picto> picList;

    for(int i = 0; i < picNames.size(); i++){
        QString picName = picNames.at(i);
        QGraphicsTextItem *label = new QGraphicsTextItem();
        label->setPlainText(picName);
        QGraphicsRectItem *rect = new QGraphicsRectItem();
        rect->setRect(0,i*20,50,20);
        label->setParentItem(rect);
        label->setPos(0,0);
        this->addItem(rect);
        qDebug()<< rect->pos(); //always return (0,0)
    }
    return picList;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried this code with several variations, but I can't solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    QString picName = "Sample";
    QGraphicsTextItem *label = new QGraphicsTextItem();
    label->setPlainText(picName);
    QGraphicsRectItem *rect = new QGraphicsRectItem();
    rect->setRect(0,i*50,50,20);
    label->setParentItem(rect);
    label->moveBy(0,i*50);//new
    //or label->setPos(0,i*50);
    this->addItem(rect);
    qDebug()<< rect->pos();
}
```

Output of     `qDebug()<< rect->rect()<< label->scenePos();`

```
QRectF(0,0 50x20) QPointF(0, 0) 
QRectF(0,50 50x20) QPointF(0, 50) 
QRectF(0,100 50x20) QPointF(0, 100) 
QRectF(0,150 50x20) QPointF(0, 150) 
QRectF(0,200 50x20) QPointF(0, 200)
```

Result:

[image]

Edit:

Calling `setRect()` on a `QGraphicsRectItem` does not change its `pos()`, it just changes the position of the rectangle that it draws, but the item's position is unchanged. So you can set rect as `(0, 0)` and call `setPos()` to move item where you want. So next code is slightly different but result on scene is absolutely same.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    QString picName = "Sample";
    QGraphicsRectItem *rect = new QGraphicsRectItem();
    QGraphicsTextItem *label = new QGraphicsTextItem();
    label->setPlainText(picName);
    rect->setRect(0,0,50,20);
    rect->setPos(0,i*50);
    //rect->moveBy(0,i*50);
    label->setParentItem(rect);
    //label->setPos(0,i*50);
    this->addItem(rect);
}
```

In this case `pos()` returns correct value

Comment: That means you have to move the label itself doesn't it? I tough it should move with it's parent, the rect since it's position is supposed to be relative to the parent.

Comment: @Laetan Yes I move label. And yes, it relative to the parent but as you said, your parent has 0,0 coordinates every time, so coordinates of label is 0,0 too.

Comment: I know but that's the problem. Why does the rect always have (0,0) when they obviously are not located at the 0,0 position on the view, and how do I make it so the correct position is used for the childs items?

Comment: @Laetan I added detail explanation. See my edit please.

Comment: Wonderful! I though the constructor was doing the setPos. Thanks a lot!